# Wamp no logra levantar

Tags: servidor, wamp

Instale **WAMP** en mi local, al intentar iniciar solo queda en color naranjo.
estube revisando los log de errores de apache y php y solo en **mysql** tengo escritura:

```
  180831 13:15:54 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
  180831 13:15:54 InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
  180831 13:15:54 InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
  180831 13:15:54 InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
  180831 13:15:54 InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
  180831 13:15:54 InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
  180831 13:15:55 InnoDB: highest supported file format is Barracuda.
  180831 13:15:55  InnoDB: Waiting for the background threads to start
  180831 13:15:56 InnoDB: 1.1.8 started; log sequence number 3653946
  180831 13:15:56 [Note] Server hostname (bind-address): '(null)'; port: 3306
  180831 13:15:56 [Note]   - '(null)' resolves to '::';
  180831 13:15:56 [Note]   - '(null)' resolves to '0.0.0.0';
  180831 13:15:56 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '0.0.0.0'.
  180831 13:15:56 [Note] Event Scheduler: Loaded 0 events
  180831 13:15:56 [Note] wampmysqld: ready for connections.
  Version: '5.5.24-log'  socket: ''  port: 3306  MySQL Community Server (GPL)
  180831 13:20:14 [Note] wampmysqld: Normal shutdown
```

Este pc tenia instalado un **apache** un **php** y un **mysql**, por ende deduzco que lo utilizaban talvez anteriormente para levantar un server,
pienso que por allí puede estar el problema talves que **WAMP** no logre levantar.

en la sección de servicios solo figura iniciado wampmysql, y para wampapache al intentar iniciar desde servicios me arroja este mensaje microsoft:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Lo mas probable es que tengas corriendo los servicios anteriores, deberías ir a Servicios y verificar que estén detenidos los antiguos ya que están disponiendo del puerto que esta utilizando WAMP

Comment: gracias lo revisare ;)

Comment: MySQL80 es el unico que figura iniciado,que es el que instale cuando instale MySQL Workbench, lo baje e intente volver a iniciar WAMP y persiste el problema.

Comment: Realiza un scanner de los puertos y verifica que el puerto `3306` no salga en la lista: https://support.kaspersky.com/mx/101